# How to deal with the conflicts of different libraries' version in different branches in pom?

Tags: git, maven, pom.xml

I have a common dependency with different versions in different branches.

For example, its version name is dev-0.01 in the dev branch, uat-0.01 in the uat branch, prd-0.01 in the prd branch.

The reason is the new feature will be only in the dev first, then to uat, finally to prod.

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from just changing the version when dev is merged into uat then into prd?

Comment: @Kim check out the prd branch as a new branch to change the code. Then, merge the new branch to dev branch. but the conflict occurs in the pom.xml between two branches